# Currency 'USD' not found when trying to access admin

Tags: magento-1.7, currency, zend-framework, multicurrency

I have never encountered this error before. I did a quick search for it. I found another thread but it seemed to vary a bit from my problem.

Here is my stack trace:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Currency 'USD' not found

Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(575): Zend_Currency->__construct('USD', Object(Zend_Locale))
#1 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(233): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->currency('USD')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(216): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatTxt('444.00000000', Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(197): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatPrecision('444.00000000', 2, Array, true, false)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Bar.php(82): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->format('444.00000000')
#5 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Bar.php(62): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar->format('444.00000000')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Totals.php(74): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar->addTotal('Revenue', '444.00000000')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Totals->_prepareLayout()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#9 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard.php(50): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#12 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#13 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#14 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#15 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#16 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#19 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#20 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#22 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /var/www/vhosts/inc.com/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed i had to clear memcache

```
service memcached restart
```

Additionally,

```
var/cache
var/sessions
```